# Breaking keys into deep Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to iterate through the following array, and break into objects, from:

```
data = [
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 1},
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 2},
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 3},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 1},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 2},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 3},
  {k: "a_c_a", v: 1},
  {k: "a_c_b", v: 2},
  {k: "a_d", v: 1},
  {k: "a_d", v: 2}
]
```

to:

```
result = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [1,2,3],
      d: [1,2,3]
    },
    c: {
      a: [1],
      b: [2]
    },
    d: [1,2]
  },
}
```

any ideas on achieving this neatly?

Comment: I've tried iterating though the array, splitting the keys and re-embedding them either as objects (for sons) or as arrays on limits (and then pushing the data), but I haven't managed to achieve the desired result all together. I suppose there's a need of a re-cross function but my mind is already blown by this I need an outside intervention.

Comment: I recommend posting your code.

Comment: You need to make it an array or add keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some horrible code to do that:

```
var data = [
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 1},
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 2},
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 3},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 1},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 2},
  {k: "a_b_d", v: 3},
  {k: "a_c_a", v: 1},
  {k: "a_c_b", v: 2}
];

var result ={};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  var keys = item.k.split("_");
  var entryPoint = result;
  var l = keys.length-1;
  keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
    if (!entryPoint[key])
      entryPoint[key] = (index == l) ? [] : {};
    entryPoint = entryPoint[key];
  });
  entryPoint.push(item.v);
});
```

It fails if you have both sub-keys and values at the same level. (Requires some change the output format to fix.)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT : The OP has changed the way data was presented in the question.
The following solution is correct for the previous data as mentioned in the code.

**The object you mentioned is invalid. There cannot be duplicate keys**.
However , with unique keys, this should be the way to achieve this :

```
var result = {};

data = {
  "a_b_c": 1,
  "a_b_c": 2,
  "a_b_c": 3,
  "a_b_d": 1,
  "a_b_d": 2,
  "a_b_d": 3,
  "a_c_a": 1,
  "a_c_b": 2
}


for(the_key in data)
{
    new_keys = the_key.split("_");
    result[new_keys[0]] =  result[new_keys[0]] || {};
    result[new_keys[0]][new_keys[1]] = result[new_keys[0]][new_keys[1]]|| {};
    result[new_keys[0]][new_keys[1]][new_keys[2]] = result[new_keys[0]][new_keys[1]][new_keys[2]] || [];
    result[new_keys[0]][new_keys[1]][new_keys[2]].push(data[the_key]);
}


console.log(result);
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8ZbMt/

Comment: It's probably worth specifying that this only works for x_x_x keys (which seems to be the case here). For shorter or longer keys, it needs to be generalized.

Comment: that's somewhat what I've done, but I'd like the function to be generic, accepting indefinite depth on array
i.e "a_c_c_a", "a_c_c_b"

Comment: @SagiIsha That is easy to do, you just have to replace inner lines with a loop equal to one less than number of subkeys to create javascript objects for them , and create an array for the last subkey

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
var data = [
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 1},
  {k: "a_b_c", v: 2},
  …
]

var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var keys = data[i].k.split("_"),
        o = result;
    for (var j=0; j<keys.length-1; j++)
        o = o[keys[j]] || (o[keys[j]] = {});
    o = o[keys[j]] || (o[keys[j]] = []);
    o.push(data[i].v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a data structure that goes by the names of Trie, Digital Search Tree or Retrieval Tree.

Here is a [wikipedia article on tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), it contains general algorithms for building them.

Answer (score 0):

My entry as follows :

```
rslt = data.reduce (function (rslt, d) {
  for (var traverse = rslt, keys = d.k.split ('_'); keys.length > 1;) {
    !traverse.hasOwnProperty (keys[0]) && (traverse[keys[0]] = {});
    traverse = traverse[keys.shift ()];
  }  

  !traverse.hasOwnProperty (keys = keys[0]) && (traverse[keys] = []);
  traverse[keys].push (d.v);
  return rslt;
}, {});
```